# Split multiple string in Lua

Tags: lua

I have the following string:

example = "1,3,4-7,9,13-17"

With these values ​​I want the next array: 1,3,4,5,6,7,9,13,14,15,16,17

With the script below I get the values ​​between the commas, but how do I get the rest.

```
teststring = "1,3,4-7,9,13-17"
testtable=split(teststring, ",");
for i = 1,#testtable do
  print(testtable[i])
end;

function split(pString, pPattern)

  local Table = {}  -- NOTE: use {n = 0} in Lua-5.0
  local fpat = "(.-)" .. pPattern
  local last_end = 1
  local s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, 1)
  while s do
    if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then
      table.insert(Table,cap)
    end
    last_end = e+1
    s, e, cap = pString:find(fpat, last_end)
  end
  if last_end <= #pString then
    cap = pString:sub(last_end)
    table.insert(Table, cap)
 end
 return Table
end
```

Output

1

3

4-7

9

13-17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code solves your problem, given that your input string sticks to that format

```
local test = "1,3,4-7,8,9-12"
local numbers = {}
for number1, number2 in string.gmatch(test, "(%d+)%-?(%d*)") do
  number1 = tonumber(number1)
  number2 = tonumber(number2)

  if number2 then
    for i = number1, number2 do
      table.insert(numbers, i)
    end
  else
    table.insert(numbers, number1)
  end

end
```

First we use `string.gmatch` to iterate over the string. The pattern will match one or more digits, followed by one or zero "-", followed by zero or more digits. By using captures we make sure that `number1` is the first number and `number2` is the second number if we actually have an interval given. If we have an interval given we create the numbers in between using a for loop from `number1` to `number2`. If we don't have an interval `number2` is nil and we only have `number1`so  we only insert that.

Please refer to the Lua Reference Manual - [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1) and [string.gmatch](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch) for further details

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
for _, v in ipairs(testtable) do    
  if string.match(v,'%-') then
    local t= {}
    for word in string.gmatch(v, '[^%-]+') do
      table.insert(t, word)
    end    
    for i = t[1],t[2] do print(i) end        
  else
   print (v)
  end
end
```

Comment: note that you don't need a capture if your pattern only consists of what you capture.